# cursor not changing on custom control exit

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, .net-4.0, cursor

I had this problem: I created a custom control (C#, WinForms, Framework 4.0) in which I need to change cursor when user presses some key (this works); exiting from control I want to restore to previous cursor.. but that doesn't work: exiting cursor remains current one. What's wrong?

```
protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
{
    oldCursor = Cursor;
    base.OnMouseEnter(e);
}

protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor = oldCursor;
    base.OnMouseLeave(e);
}
```

When button is pressed I do:

```
this.Cursor = NewCursor.CreateCursor(
    Properties.Resources.cur_ZoomIn, 14, 9, Color.White);
```

where

```
public static Cursor CreateCursor(
    Bitmap bmp_parm, int xHotSpot, int yHotSpot, Color? transparent)
{
    Image img = bmp_parm;
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img, new Size(img.Width, img.Height));
    if (transparent.HasValue) bmp.MakeTransparent(transparent.Value);

    if (cursor != IntPtr.Zero)
        DestroyIcon(cursor);

    IntPtr ptr = bmp.GetHicon();
    IconInfo tmp = new IconInfo();
    GetIconInfo(ptr, ref tmp);
    tmp.xHotspot = xHotSpot;
    tmp.yHotspot = yHotSpot;
    tmp.fIcon = false;
    cursor = CreateIconIndirect(ref tmp);

    if (tmp.hbmColor != IntPtr.Zero) DeleteObject(tmp.hbmColor);
    if (tmp.hbmMask != IntPtr.Zero) DeleteObject(tmp.hbmMask);
    if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero) DestroyIcon(ptr);

    return new Cursor(cursor);
}
```

I googled around (for example [here](http://www.doogal.co.uk/cursor.php) and elsewhere) and my code seems right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute this:

```
oldCursor = Cursor;
```

you simply pass the reference to your `Cursor` field. After that you change this field:

```
this.Cursor = NewCursor.CreateCursor(
    Properties.Resources.cur_ZoomIn, 14, 9, Color.White);
```

This changes the `oldCursor` field also, as reference type object.
So you should change the way you save `oldCursor`.

Comment: Yes @VMAtm, you're right (I've already thought about this) and thanks for your answer!! The problem is I have no experience on saving and restoring cursors...

Comment: @Marco Or you still have a problem with that?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to save cursor in a different way. Examples I saw on google are like my code... so I don't know what to do...

Comment: @Marco Did you try `this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;`?